# Android NDK does not print when inside thread

Tags: android, c, multithreading, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I'm running a GLSurfaceView with the renderer containing the following functions:

```java
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        Engine.NativeMain();
        Engine.logicThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while(Engine.isRunning)
                {
                    Engine.NativeUpdate();
                    try{ Thread.sleep(16); }
                    catch(InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
        });
        Engine.logicThread.start();
        GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
    {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
        //By doing that, it is possible to save little battery when the renderer
        //is not dirty
        Engine.NativeRender();
    }
```

If I move out Engine.NativeUpdate onto onDrawFrame, it prints okay. But inside that other thread, it does everything but print. I'm using __android_log_print for that task. In my native code I guaranteed that I wasn't using any thread local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't logging anything because I guaranteed my game loop was not inside thread local storage. But I was setting a callback function which would call __android_log_print. That callback was thread local storage, so, it was null, thus, not being called